# why does future::future() not work with dbAppendTable in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, promise, future

you can use future() for its side effects, e.g. to write a file:

```
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)
future({write.csv(mtcars,"mtcars.csv")})
```

but you can't with a database call:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
future({
dbCreateTable(con, "iris", iris)
})
dbReadTable(con, "iris") # gives error
```

(the table is not created whether writing persistently or in memory.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DBI` package and all their implementations (like `RSQLite`) do use **non-exportable objects** (basically memory pointers), see:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html

You can see an error message when you configure `futures` like this:

```
options(future.globals.onReference = "error")
# ... your code goes here

# Error in FALSE : 
# Detected a non-exportable reference (‘externalptr’) in one of the globals (‘con’ of class ‘SQLiteConnection’) used in the future expression
# Timing stopped at: 0.028 0 0.028
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I suspect that the two `con` are not the same, so I guess that future is like Bangkok in hangover: **What happens inside the future stays inside the future**. Your `con` is, so to say, evaluated by value (not by reference), so the table is not written into the original `con`. Consider the following code:

```r
library(future)
x <- 4
a <- future({
    x <- x + 1 # I am not seen outside
})
x # is still 4 and has not changed
#> [1] 4
value(a) # is 5
#> [1] 5
```

However, if you use `substitute = FALSE` in your `future`, `x` will be `5` as well and I'd be happy to know why :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using futures with database connections you have to create (and probably close) the connection inside the future:

```r
library(RSQLite)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

future({
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con))
dbCreateTable(con, "iris", iris)
})
# reconnect and read
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbReadTable(con, "iris") 
#data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

There's an open issue about this on [github](https://github.com/rstudio/pool/issues/83)